# Sublime Text 2 Auto file path completion

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I am looking for an Auto file path completion in Sublime 2 Text like ctrl + x + o in VIM

How do i do that?

Thank you

Comment: Probably you want CMD + T (osx) - feature called Go To Anywhere http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/05/11/sublime-text-2-tips-for-python-and-web-developers/#Go_to_anywhere_shortcut

Comment: hmm no its a nice feature but not what i am looking for.
For example when u open an image tag in html <img src="">. For the src attribute i want to have a little browser pop up starting from the realtive path of my file.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Think you want something like [AutoFileName](https://github.com/BoundInCode/AutoFileName).

Answer (score 5):

AutoFileName is outdated and not supported anymore, last update was 2 years ago.

Better plugin for file path completion is [FuzzyFilePath](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/FuzzyFilePath).

In addition to file path completion you'll get the nice bonus: <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> opens the file under cursor.

Comment: AutoFileName  does this correctly and easily. FuzzyFilePath does NOT do this well, the way AutoFileName does. In fact I could not get any kind of intellisense for the file name/path for my ST2 when I used FuzzyFilePath .

Comment: Thanks for the tip Temp O'rary.  I have autofilename working well on ST2